# Mismatched input/output channel dimension in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I'm currently working on a multi class image segmentation with Keras.
My input images are in RGB format. 
I'm trying to segment 4 types of objects in the image.

My neural network is as follows:

```
inputs = Input((patch_size, patch_size,nb_chan))

#
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv1)

#
conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv2)

#
conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv3)

conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)

#
merge1 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv4)
merge1 = concatenate([conv3,merge1],axis=3)
conv5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(merge1)
conv5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

#
merge2 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5)
merge2 = concatenate([conv2,merge2], axis=3)
conv6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(merge2)
conv6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

#
merge3 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6)
merge3 = concatenate([conv1,merge3], axis=3)
conv7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(merge3)
conv7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)


conv8 = Conv2D(nbClass, (1, 1), activation='softmax',padding='same')(conv7)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv8)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

My input image size is 256*256
nb_chan is the input channel size, in my case it is 3.
nbClass is the number of object to segment, in my case it is 4.

But when I want to compile my model I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_15 to have shape (256, 256, 4) but got array with shape (256, 256, 3)
```

I tried to modify the last layer of my network with a reshape function:

```
conv8 = Conv2D(nbClass, (1, 1), activation='softmax',padding='same')(conv7)
conv8 = Reshape((patch_size*patch_size,nbClass))(conv8)
conv8 = core.Permute((2,1))(conv8)
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected permute_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 256, 256, 3)
```

I'm a bit lost, did I forget something ?

Comment: The first error happens at fit, not compile, and it clearly says that it expects a 4-channel output image, while you provided a 3-channel image, sounds like either you have only 3 classes of objects (not 4), or there is a problem in the code that builds the targets for your model.

Comment: check input shape and model summary. There is definitely a mismatch somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. The problem is I don't really know how to do a multi segmentation.
In fact, my ground truth images are also RGB images with 4 different colors (black, blue, green, red) for each object to segment. 
And I naively thought that the result of the prediction would have been a size 4 array with the percentage for each pixel to belong to a class.

Comment: No, you need to convert your "color encoded image" to a one-hot encoded image, which will have shape (256, 256, 4), where each channel will encode one of the classes.

Comment: I will try that, thank you for your help !